# subprocess.call doesn't work unless I precede the command with "python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Subprocess.call works only when I run it using the word "python" while on another computer it works without preceding the command with "python"

```
filename_arg1 = "python display_CDF_graph.py" + " \'" + full_path + 'congestions_distribution.csv' + "\'" 
subprocess.call(filename_arg1, shell=True)
```

vs.

```
filename_arg1 = "display_CDF_graph.py" + " \'" + full_path + 'congestions_distribution.csv' + "\'" 
subprocess.call(filename_arg1, shell=True)
```

does anybody know why?

EDIT: running it without the word "python" on the other computer would just open the .py file without executing it.

Comment: Does the file you're running have a she-bang line? Something like `#! /usr/bin/python`?

Comment: Do you observe the same difference if you try those commands at the command line?

Comment: @rdas No it does not but I tested it and nothing changed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No there is no difference but both ways would just open the .py file. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use **Linux** and the two computers have exactly the same file contents, you need to make the file executable from the command line:

```
# pick one
chmod 755 display_CDF_graph.py
chmod +x display_CDF_graph.py
```

If you copied the file from one to the other using `scp` (secure copy), you can use the `-p` option to preserve the executable bit:

```
scp -p display_CDF_graph.py other:/path/to/folder/
```

If you're using **Windows**, you need to setup the [python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher), which is called `pythonw.exe` to be associated with files having he `.py` extension. This is an option during installation. If you didn't select the option or somehow changed the file association in the meantime, [the older python 3.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html) says:

1. Launch a command prompt.
2. Associate the correct file group with .py scripts:

   `assoc .py=Python.File`
3. Redirect all Python files to the new executable:

   `ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\pythonw.exe "%1" %*`

Comment: It is windows not linux and I checked the permissions they were all ok. Thanks for your time answering this question.